# Don't know why the switch control always send false Value

Tags: xcode, swift, switch-statement, watchkit

I make a simple WKInterface with a switch control and make a function for that switch to show up the value of switch like this:
[image]

I don't know why when test the switch,the result I received always false? please explain and show me how to fix. As I thought the out put of that switch will change from false to true and move on like that.. What's wrong in here? or the Xcode's bug with switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. First declare outlet for switch like this:

   ```
     @IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!
   ```
2. In viewDidLoad implement listener (target-action):

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

         mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: "switchChangedValue:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
   }
   ```
3. Declare this function where you will get response every time switch value is changed:

   ```
   func switchChangedValue(sender:UISwitch){
    if sender.isKindOfClass(UISwitch){
       if sender.on {
           println("Switch is ON")
           println("\(sender.on)")
       } else {
           println("Switch is OFF")
           println("\(sender.on)")
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: I know I can do like that. But I dont know why my switch on my code is not working like normal. As I thought, when I ctrl and drag the switch to code and using action. the output of switch will change from true to false and so on, but with my code the output is always false not depend on the state of switch.

Comment: You missed on detail. You must read "value.on".  That is method of uiswitch.  If you read just value its not enough. If value.on is true then switch is on. Otherwise is off. That method "on" will read if switch is on.

Answer (score 2):

Here, instead of passing value of type `Bool`, pass it as a `UISwitch`:

```
@IBAction func testSwitchPressed(value: UISwitch) {
  println(value.on)
}
```

This will correctly tell if if your `switch` is on or off.

This is great because you can use `Control Flow` as well with this:

```
@IBAction func testSwitchPressed(value: UISwitch) {
  //println(value.on)
  if value.on {
    println("The switch has been enabled!")
    //cool features here
  } else {
    println("The switch has been disabled!")
    //other cool features here
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: If you press CTRL and drag the mouse in the InterfaceController source code,  the following function is automatically added: <code>- (IBAction)test:(BOOL)value {
}.</code> And value is correct.

Comment: when I change the Bool --> UISwitch , My code will got error when I ran the code

Comment: Go ahead and `re-link` your `UISlider`'s connection. **Don't** forget to `control click` your `UISlider` in your *Main.storyboard* and `disconnect` your current connection to `testSwitchPressed` before `re-linking` your `UISlider` to your *View Controller*. @HieuDucPham

Answer (score 1):

the IBAction function passes the UIElement which triggered the action.
So use something like this

```
  @IBAction func testSwitchPressed(sender : UISwitch)
  {
    println(sender.on)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you press CTRL and drag the mouse in the InterfaceController source code,  the following function is automatically added:

-(IBAction)TapOnSwitch:(BOOL)value
{
}

And value is correct.
This is valid if you want check the value when the user change the value of the switch.

Comment: I know it's correct when I Ctrl and Drag the switch to the code but the problem is: although I did as you said but I always got the output value is false.